# Content bounce back issue while scrolling a div upwards using iscroll.js on Chrome on iPhone using iOS 8

Tags: ios8, scroll, iscroll, mobile-chrome

While scrolling a div using iscroll.js on Chrome on IOS 8, if I scroll upwards and take the finger out of bounds of the scrollable div, the content follows the movement and the div is left blank (the last list item has reached the top of the div). On removing the finger it doesn't bounce back (as it does when I scroll downwards)

The content returns (bounces back into the div) when i tap in the DIV again.

This issue is specific to Chrome on IOS 8. Other places it works fine.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

This is what the device looks like after scrolling out of bounds:

[image]